# Systemcall child-parent execution problem (fork execve) Linux

Tags: c, fork, parent-child, cpu, system-calls

Im new to systemcall. Im using execve inside a child so the parent should run as normal and not be ovewritten by execve. The problem is that the child executes and stops the whole thing after execve. My goal here is to count the number of clone executed in the bash command(argument) executed by execve.

Ive read the man, Im still a bit confused.
I can only use ptrace, fork, wait/waitpid.

argument:

```
/bin/bash -c "echo 'first test' | wc -c"
```

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    pid_t child_pid = fork();
    int status;
    int counter = 0;
    wait(&status);
    if (child_pid == -1) {
        exit(1);
    } else {
        while(status != child_pid){
            if (child_pid == 0) {
                ptrace(PTRACE_TRACEME, child_pid, 0, 0);
                raise(SIGSTOP);
                execve(argv[1], &argv[1], NULL);
                ptrace(PTRACE_SETOPTIONS, child_pid, 0, PTRACE_O_TRACECLONE);
                ptrace(PTRACE_CONT, child_pid, 0L, 0L);
                if(status>>8 == (SIGTRAP | (PTRACE_EVENT_CLONE<<8)))
                    counter++;
            }
        }
    }
    printf("# of clone executions: %d", counter);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It is very unusual to call `wait` in the child.  You typically have the parent and the child follow different code paths immediately after the fork.  (eg `switch( pid = fork() ) ...`

Comment: The status from `wait()` is unrelated to the PID of the process.  You'd need `pid_t corpse = wait(&status);` and then test `while (corpse != child_pid)` (maybe … that would be more logical than what's shown, at least).  The `raise(SIGSTOP)` should stop the process that executes it — the following `execve()` won't be executed until the process is sent a `SIGCONT` signal.  The code is organized peculiarly.  You should normally have `pid_t pid = fork(); if (pid < 0) { …failed to fork… } else if (pid == 0) { be_childish(); } else { be_parental(); }` or equivalent.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler yes, its written particularly bc my understanding of this is not perfect. Thanks for the feedback

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`execve` will overwrite the child process, so any instruction after `execve` will not be executed, unless the call to `execve` fails. You should instead run the `ptrace` tracing that appears after the `execve` in the parent process

Edit: here is a commented solution to count the number of clone syscalls:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <sys/ptrace.h>
#include <sys/syscall.h>
#include <sys/reg.h> // ORIG_RAX

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  pid_t child_pid = fork();
  int counter = 0;
  int entering_syscall = 1;

  if(child_pid == -1) {
    perror("fork failed");
    exit(1);
  } else if(child_pid != 0) {
    // parent
    u_int64_t rax;
    int status;

    while(1) {
      // wait for the next signal by the child
      if(wait(&status) != child_pid)
        continue;

      if(WIFEXITED(status)) {
        puts("child exited");
        break;
      }

      // read the USER area, defined in sys/user.h, which contains the registers information
      // in linux, rax contains the syscall number
      rax = ptrace(PTRACE_PEEKUSER, child_pid, 8 * ORIG_RAX, NULL);

      if(rax == SYS_clone /* 56 */) {
        // PTRACE_SYSCALL generates a signal both when entering and exiting a syscall
        // only count the syscall during enter
        if(entering_syscall)
          counter++;

        entering_syscall = !entering_syscall;
      }

      //printf("syscall %ld\n", rax);

      // continue the child process until the next syscall enter/exit
      ptrace(PTRACE_SYSCALL, child_pid, NULL, NULL);
    }
  } else {
    // child

    // turns the calling thread into a tracee
    ptrace(PTRACE_TRACEME, child_pid, 0, 0);

    // signal and wait for the parent. This ensures that PTRACE_SYSCALL
    // will not miss any child syscall
    raise(SIGSTOP);

    execve(argv[1], &argv[1], NULL);

    // should be never reached
    perror("execve failed");
    exit(1);
  }

  printf("Num clone: %d\n", counter);
}
```

You can cross-check it against strace `strace 2>&1 your_command | grep clone | wc -l`

Comment: @JonathanLeffler one thing that Im missing here though, how is the number of clone read if execve is executed in the child process and terminated right after so the info of the its systemcalls is nowhere to be found. So ptracing(options) in the parent process wont have any data to read/analyze from.

Comment: @Olivia22: I'm not sure how the ptrace functionality works, and that's why I've not answered.  I've not needed to worry about that this millennium (or, indeed, for some of the latter part of the last millennium).  I don't know what the timing issues are, if any.  If you carefully identify what the parent is to execute and what the child is to execute, then you may be correct to use `raise(SIGSTOP)` in the child, and the parent can either use `kill(SIGCONT, child_pid)` or use a ptrace-specific call to allow the child to proceed through the `execve()` knowing that the necessary setup is done.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Ok thats super insightful, its given me more ideas and I understand it a bit better. thanks alot!

Comment: @Olivia22 check my edited answer with a commented example